# Debian - Clone system

Tags: debian, clonezilla

I am running on Debian (testing) with cinnamon graphical environment. 
Each time I change my computer, I am lazy to do all the basic stuff (reinstall all the software, configuration files ...) so I would like to create a clone of my machine.
However, how this procedure can be clean ?

- I mean if it's a copy of all bytes of the system partition /, I should use the same machine (for the drivers ...) so that I don't need to remove paquets or install new ones on the new machine ?

What is the best way to perform this procedure ?
I read about clonezilla, dd but I am not convinced  by how they perform the clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly Linux lets you get away with a *lot*, moving between PCs with the same architecture.  Always entertains me how well it works moving a system disk between machines.

I wouldn't quite call that clean though.  One example you might end up with is NetworkManager configurations for old network cards.

I have the same feeling right now.  I think it's a signal to put a bit more work into getting organized :).

My thinking is one should write a record of config files (or directories) you've changed.  It's useful to keep track of your reasons.  Then you can copy over what you need.  *After* installing the packages that use them.  So maybe worth holding a copy of your old `/etc`, rather than trying to install all packages and configs in one go.

If the logs start to build up, you can start writing a prioritized summary of what you need on a system.  Lower priorities are old experiments you no longer use very often, and packages that will be easy to identify and re-install when you actually want them.

It can be good to install `etckeeper` first, using it to record the config files as initially installed by the packages.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `etckeeper`

Answer (score 0):

How much stuff do you need to be moved over? If you don't have many personal files, but mostly installed programs and configurations, you could look into `LinuxRespin` which is a fork of `remastersys`. It lets you build a custom distributable iso which can be installed on computers and will contain programs and configurations that you had on the original system. There is a size limit, which is why this will only really be helpful if you don't have a ton of files.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a Linux live media , mount your external Hard drive then backup your drive using the command `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/sdx | gzip > /path_to/backup.gz
```

To restore the backup run:

```
gzip -dc /path_to/backup.gz | dd of=/dev/sdx
```

Also you can clone the entire hd :

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy bs=64K conv=noerror,sync
```

Comment: The backup should be on the same type machine ? 
The 'dd' command is a copy byte to byte ? so for instance, drivers/librairies needed for the older machine are useless for the new one ... hence it's not that proper.

I will soon try the method describe by @sourcejedi, apparently just save the configuration files are great help. I should look for also backup the list of paquets that are installed.
Now I study if clonezilla/etckeeper... can do this stuff in a proper way.